# PropertyNotFoundException exception in the JSP page

Tags: jsp, el, propertynotfoundexception

I'm trying to edit my entity through a JSP page

```
<jsp:include page="menuEditarDisciplina.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="idDisciplina" value='<%=request.getParameter("id")%>'/>
</jsp:include>
```

The servlet code I'm using

```
public class InsereDisciplina implements Logica {

    private ClienteRestDisciplina clienteRestDisciplina;
    private ClienteRestCurso clienteRestCurso;

    public void executa(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws Exception {
        clienteRestDisciplina = new ClienteRestDisciplina();
        clienteRestCurso = new ClienteRestCurso();

        String idCursoS = req.getParameter("idCurso");
        Integer idCurso = (idCursoS != null) ? Integer.parseInt(idCursoS)
                : null;

        String idProfessorS = req.getParameter("idProfessor");
        Integer idProfessor = (idProfessorS != null) ? Integer
                .parseInt(idProfessorS) : null;

        String idDisciplinaS = req.getParameter("id");
        Integer idDisciplina = (idDisciplinaS != null) ? Integer
                .parseInt(idDisciplinaS) : null;

        Disciplina disciplina = idDisciplina == null ? new Disciplina()
                : clienteRestDisciplina.getDisciplina(idDisciplina);

        disciplina.setNome(req.getParameter("nome"));
        disciplina.setSala(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("sala")));

        String dataString = req.getParameter("horario").toString();

        disciplina.setHorario(Date.valueOf(dataString));
        disciplina.setCargaHoraria(Integer.parseInt(req
                .getParameter("cargaHoraria")));
        disciplina.setDescricao(req.getParameter("descricao"));

        if (disciplina.getIdDisciplina() != null) {
            clienteRestDisciplina.editarDisciplina(disciplina);
        } else {
            clienteRestCurso.inserirDisciplinaNoCurso(idCurso, idProfessor,
                    disciplina);
        }

        res.sendRedirect("disciplina/listarDisciplinas.jsp");

    }

}
```

My Java bean class as below

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Disciplina implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;

    public Disciplina() {
    }

    public Disciplina(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Disciplina(Integer id, String nome, String descricao, int cargaHoraria, Date horario, int sala) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.cargaHoraria = cargaHoraria;
        this.horario = horario;
        this.sala = sala;
    }   

    public Integer getIdDisciplina() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setIdDisciplina(Integer idDisciplina) {
        this.id = idDisciplina;
    }

    // ...

}
```

But it gives an exception :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'br.icmc.usp.modelo.Disciplina' does not have the property 'id'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:664)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:293)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:120)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1009)
    at org.apache.jsp.disciplina.editarDisciplina_jsp._jspService(editarDisciplina_jsp.java:99)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
```

Why am I receiving a `PropertyNotFoundException` exception? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an EL related error. Not the scriptlet code error. EL works on getter setters.

change your getter setter

```
public Integer getIdDisciplina() {
    return id;
}

public void setIdDisciplina(Integer idDisciplina) {
    this.id = idDisciplina;
}
```

to

```
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer idDisciplina) {
        this.id = idDisciplina;
    }
```